# How to open multiple files with file names matching pattern in intelij

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Say, I have several files in my project whose name ends with `JobTasklet.java`. Is there a way to open all these files in one go in `Intelij Idea`. Lets also assume that all these files are in the same package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok! got the answer. Use `CTRL + N` to search file. In the search box, fill in the pattern. Once you get the list of files, simply select all files that you want to open. Multiple selection is allowed in this drop down. Leaving this answer for someone with same doubt.

Comment: Did you mean CTRL + SHIFT + N ?

Comment: Both of them work. And the best part is that the files do not need to be in the same package.

Comment: Actually, `Ctrl+N` performs classes lookup. Of course, this works when you're looking for .java files. Files lookup is under `Ctrl + Shift + N` shortcut.